# Visual Studio Online Automated Build Failing on Nuget Packages On Some Projects but not all

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-deploy

For some reason one of my projects is not building when I build. The advice that I keep getting on every page I look at tells me that I should "Enable Nuget Package Restore" for my solution. I have already done this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the output of that build:

```
Overall Build Process

00:00
Update Build Number

02:27
Run On Agent (reserved build agent Hosted Build Agent)

00:00
Create Workspace

00:35
Get Workspace

00:01
Create Label

01:21
Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items

01:21
Compile and Test

01:15
Run MSBuild for Project

00:59
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouseMVC.sln for default targets.

00:44
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouse.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:16
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Common/projectnameWarehouse.Common.csproj for default targets.

00:09
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Core/projectnameWarehouse.Core.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Common/projectnameWarehouse.Common.csproj for default targets.

00:02
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.DAL/projectnameWarehouse.DAL.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Common/projectnameWarehouse.Common.csproj for default targets.

00:02
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Common/projectnameWarehouse.Common.csproj for default targets.
 InventoryDAO.cs (210): The variable 'rows' is assigned but its value is never used

00:01
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Services/projectnameWarehouse.Services.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PushSharp.Android". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PushSharp.Apple". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PushSharp.Core". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PushSharp.Windows". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (1605): Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "PushSharp.WindowsPhone". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
 Models\Audience.cs (6): The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\Notification.cs (6): The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (6): The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Push\PushSharpPushService.cs (8): The type or namespace name 'PushSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Push\PushSharpPushService.cs (9): The type or namespace name 'PushSharp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Push\PushSharpPushService.cs (15): The type or namespace name 'PushBroker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Push\PushSharpPushService.cs (19): The type or namespace name 'PushBroker' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\Audience.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\Audience.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'JsonPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\Notification.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\Notification.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'JsonPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'JsonPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (14): The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (14): The type or namespace name 'JsonPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (16): The type or namespace name 'JsonProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
 Models\PushObject.cs (16): The type or namespace name 'JsonPropertyAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.DAL/projectnameWarehouse.DAL.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Services/projectnameWarehouse.Services.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Common/projectnameWarehouse.Common.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.DAL/projectnameWarehouse.DAL.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Services/projectnameWarehouse.Services.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Core/projectnameWarehouse.Core.csproj for default targets.

00:02
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.Gateway/projectname.GlobalAccess.Gateway.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:01
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.Worker/projectname.GlobalAccess.Worker.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.Core/projectname.GlobalAccess.Core.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.Core/projectname.GlobalAccess.Core.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.Worker/projectname.GlobalAccess.Worker.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.RunQueue/projectname.GlobalAccess.RunQueue.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectname.GlobalAccess.Worker/projectname.GlobalAccess.Worker.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Test/projectnameWarehouse.Test.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/.nuget/NuGet.targets for target(s) _DownloadNuGet.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Common/projectnameWarehouse.Common.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Core/projectnameWarehouse.Core.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.DAL/projectnameWarehouse.DAL.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices/projectnameWarehouse.NAVServices.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse.Services/projectnameWarehouse.Services.csproj for default targets.

00:00
Built $/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouseMVC-TEST/projectnameWarehouse/projectnameWarehouse.csproj for default targets.
MSBuild Log File

00:06
Handle Exception

00:06
Create Work Item

00:00
Associate Changesets and Work Items
 Exception Message: MSBuild error 1 has ended this build. You can find more specific information about the cause of this error in above messages. (type BuildProcessTerminateException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

00:02
Drop Files to Drop Location
Work item '635: Build Failure in Build: projectnameWarehouseMVC-To-QA_20141007.4' was opened by the build.
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened was that some, BUT NOT ALL, of my Nuget packages were checked into source control. I removed the "Packages" folder, that sits outside of the project folders, from source control and presto, build successful.